# Log-in Only Works When Submit button is clicked Twice

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need your help with this log-in script. When a user registers, a column `active` in the database is set to zero (0), and an activation link is sent to the email they provided. When the activation link is clicked and if successful, their respective `active` column is set to 1.

But a correct combination of username and password only works when i click the submit button twice.

On the first click i get the following lines

**Notice: Undefined index: remember in C:\wamp\www\church\login.php on line 37**

**Not Verified Yet**

But when I click the second time the log-in works.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, password
                           FROM USERS
                           WHERE username = '$username'
                           AND password = '$password'") or die (mysql_error());

        $user = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($user == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            if ($row['active'] == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_username'] = $username;
                if ($_POST['remember']) {
                    setcookie("CookieUser", $_SESSION['logged_username'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
                    setcookie("CookiePass", $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");

                    header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/church/index.php?id=1');
                }
            }
            if ($row['active'] !== 1) {
                echo "Not Verified Yet";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<div id='content' >";
            echo "<div class='OpenError' >";
            echo "Username & Password Combination Is Wrong";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there a value in `$_POST['remember']` on the first run through the code?  The error seems to indicate that there isn't.  Maybe the form isn't sending that value?

Comment: Hi, I've taken the liberty of re-formating your code *(it was really hard to read)* ; note that the line numbers might have been changed in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue *isn't* that you aren't being logged in. It's that your code does not `die()` after sending the redirect header and therefore continues executing the code on that page. Also, if the user does not select `remember`, nothing happens. To fix (the first issue), simply add `die();` *immediately after* `header("location: ...");`.

### Why do I need `die();` after `header("location: ...");`?

The `header()` function sends a string (text) to the browser (or other program requesting the page). However, the server doesn't know the difference between `header("location: ...");` and `header("somerandomthing: ...");`, so it continues executing code until it either reaches the end of the script, an error, or the client disconnects. So, to prevent code execution from continuing, simply add `die();` after *every* `header("location: ...");` call.

## Update regarding not checking 'remember'

```
<?php
if ($user == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if ($row['active'] == 1) {
            $_SESSION['logged_username'] = $username;
            if ($_POST['remember']) {
                setcookie("CookieUser", $_SESSION['logged_username'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
                setcookie("CookiePass", $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");

            }
            // Redirect even if not 'remembered'
            header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/church/index.php?id=1');
            die;
        }
        if ($row['active'] !== 1) {
            echo "Not Verified Yet";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i'm still clicking twice before I log-in.

Comment: @user1378680, what happens when you only click a single time?

Comment: When I click a single time and the checkbox having the remember is also clicked, then I'm logged in normally, but when I dont check 'Remember' and i try to login then I get a Not Verified Yet, then i'm logged in on a second click.

Comment: @user1378680, that would be because you're not redirecting at all if not 'remembered' (as I said: "Also, if the user does not select remember, nothing happens."). I've updated my answer to help you with that issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if ($_POST['remember']) {` to `if (isset($_POST['remember']) && $_POST['remember']) {`

Honestly, it should be very obvious from the error message, esp. seeing as you have the `isset` test code everywhere else in your script.

Comment: Thanks. The Undefined index is solved. But I still have to click twice  before log-in works.  Thnaks

Comment: @user1378680, see my answer to fix the log in issue.

Comment: When I click a single time and the checkbox
having the remember is also clicked, then I'm
logged in normally, but when I dont check
'Remember' and i try to login then I get a Not
Verified Yet, then i'm logged in on a second
click